# How to check javascript variabe value is empty OR null?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Should not process the ajax when the variable (`selectedFriendsList`) value is empty or null. But Here always going to if condition.
Below the sample code,

```
if(selectedFriendsList.length != 0 && selectedFriendsList !=null)
{       
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",  
        url: "ajaxShareOnFriends.php",
        data: {"postID" : postID, "selectedFriendsList" : selectedFriendsList},     
        success: function(data){
                if(data)
                {
                    alert("Shared Successfully!");
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Shared Failed!")
                }
            //alert("data=="+data);         
            //$("#total_comment").html(data);   
        }
    });
}
else{ alert("Please Select Friends!");}
```

Comment: `'null'` and `null` are not the same thing. The first is a string. If you want to check for `null`, make sure to use `null` without quotes, and also initialize the variable to `null`. There is also difference between a variable that is `null` and a variable that is not declared at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is a string then you colud use the if to check if it is non zero, becase both `null` and `''` equeal zero:

```js
var selectedFriendsList;

selectedFriendsList = '';
if(selectedFriendsList) document.write('this wont be logged');

selectedFriendsList = null;
if(selectedFriendsList) document.write('this wont be logged');


selectedFriendsList = '123123';
if(selectedFriendsList) document.write('this will be logged');
```

Comment: Thanks MoLow, Its working fine also i am clear my mistake. Lot of Thanks!

Comment: so you could mark the answer as correct if it is..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try like this:

```
if(selectedFriendsList)
```

This will evaluate to true when the `selectedFriendsList` is not null,
undefined,empty string ,0.

To add to it, when you check, `selectedFriendsList !='null'` then it is checking for the string literal `'null'` not the `null` as per your expectation.

Comment: That's a very poor answer coming from an 80K user. Without a bit of explanation about what is wrong in the question and why this would fix it, the answer is not helpful to OP and especially not for future visitors.  -edit- okay, the addition makes it better...

Comment: It not correct. It always allow When the result is empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `.length` here. An empty string evaluates to false.

```js
var str = "";

if(str) {
  console.log('not empty');
} else {
  console.log('empty');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `!!variable` trick (not not). It evaluates to either `true` if the `variable` is anything different from `null`, `undefined`, `''`(empty string), or to `false` for any of the mentioned options... in your terms:

```
if (!!selectedFriendsList) {
  //do your stuff here..
}
```

examples:

```
!!'';         // false
!!'bla';      // true
!!null;       // false
!!undefined;  // false
!!'null';     // true, since 'null' is a non empty string...
!!true;       // true
!!false;      //false
```